# How fees are calculated for new claims that replace cancelled claims?

Tags: fees, prosecution

If during response to an office action I cancel a claim and then introduce a new claim in its place then:

1. Do I have to pay a fee for the new claim or is it covered under a previously paid fees, assuming the total number of pending claims is the same.
2. Do I have to fill again the fee worksheet form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a key distinction made between withdrawn claims and canceled claims. A canceled claim subtracts from your total, a withdrawn claim does not. I know of someone - a patent attorney - who withdrew 20 claims, added twenty claims and then got a notice of fees due on having 40 total claims on file. It is unfix-able by any action after the amendment was submitted. Even if you immediately cancel the withdrawn claims you still owe on the 40 that were once on file. He *tried* to pass the bill to his client.